# Word VBA: finding a set of words and inserting predefined comments

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to automate the insertion of comments into a word document: searching for a predefined set of words (sometimes word strings, and all non case-sensitive) each to which I add a predefined comment.

There are two word sets, with two goals:

- Wordset 1: identical comment for each located word
- Wordset 2: individual comments (I suggest new text based on the word identified)

I have been semi-automating this with a code that IDs all identified words and highlights them, helping me through the process (but I still need to enter all the comments manually - and I've also been able to enter comments - but only on one word at a time.) As my VBA skills are limited, my attempts to compile a robust macro from bits of other code with similar purposes has unfortunately led me nowhere.

Below are the bits of code I've been using.

```
Sub HighlightWordList()

Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim TargetList

TargetList = Array("word1", "word2", "word3")

For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
.Text = TargetList(i)
.Format = True
.MatchCase = True
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

Loop

End With
Next

End Sub
```

The following code has been able to get me to insert bubbles directly

```
Sub CommentBubble()
'
'
Dim range As range
Set range = ActiveDocument.Content

Do While range.Find.Execute("Word x") = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range, "my comment to enter in the bubble"
Loop
End Sub
```

I've tried to have the process repeat itself by doing as shown below, but for reasons I'm certain are evident to many of you (and completely unknown to me) - this strategy has failed, working for "word x" but failing to function for all subsequent words:

```
Sub CommentBubble()
'
'
Dim range As range
Set range = ActiveDocument.Content

Do While range.Find.Execute("Word x") = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range, "my 1st comment to enter in the bubble"
Loop

Do While range.Find.Execute("Word y") = True
    ActiveDocument.Comments.Add range, "my 2nd comment to enter in the bubble"
Loop

End Sub
```

I've mixed and matched bits of these codes to no avail. Any ideas to help me with either wordset?

Thanks for everyone's help!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benoit, you're almost there! All you need to do is redefine the range object after your first loop (because it would have been exhausted at that point). Like so:

```
Sub CommentBubble()
    Dim rng As range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content

    Do While rng.Find.Execute("Word x") = True
        ActiveDocument.Comments.Add rng, "my 1st comment to enter in the bubble"
    Loop

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content ' <---------------Add This.

    Do While rng.Find.Execute("Word y") = True
        ActiveDocument.Comments.Add rng, "my 2nd comment to enter in the bubble"
    Loop
End Sub
```

That should do the trick for you (it works on my end). If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Jim! Works like a charm!

Comment: @Jim Simson , probably in this case it is working, but we should try to avoid using names for variables same as specific VBA words, like `range`, even if we are using small letters (range / Range), that's why You had to redefine the range. I don't want to be rude, just wanted to write this in educational purposes.

Comment: @Teamothy, Thanks for the pointer. It's not rude, I appreciate the feedback. I have updated my answer accordingly.